# Uncaught ReferenceError: Collection is not defined

Tags: meteor

I am doing a meteor application. I have the collection variable defined in the main.js file inside the client folder. There is also templates.js file in the same location. The Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {}; is defined inside the templates.js file. I can access the collection variable inside the rendered section, but it is not available outside it.

How can it be made possible to access the collection variable outside the 'rendered' section ?

Inside main.js

```
collectionVariable = new Meteor.Collection('collection_name');
```

Inside templates.js

```
console.log(collectionVariable); // getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: collectionVariable is not defined" here.

Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {

  //Some code. Can access the variable here.

};
```

Thanks

Comment: Tip: indent your code with four spaces to have it formatted correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind the file loading order. It appears that `templates.js` is loaded before `main.js` in your case, so the `collectionVariable` is not defined by the time it's evaluated. If you want to be sure you can use a variable in the file body, use `Meteor.startup`:

```
var localVariable;

Meteor.startup(function(){
  localVariable = collectionVariable;
  console.log(collectionVariable);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Hubert for the response. 
Yes. it looks like templates.js is running before main.js. Is there any work around for this? Like, if I create the collection in templates.js instead of main.js. Will that be a good thing to do ?  main.js is supposed to be my main client script.

Comment: First of all, most of the time collections should be in shared code area, not just on the client side - you want the same collection on the server to take advantage of synchronization. You don't want to double the code. Unless it's a local collection - but then you wouldn't use the name argument during creation.

Comment: As for the ordering, it's far better not to rely on it. You really shouldn't have this problem anyway. All the stuff that needs collections either goes to a helper / callback that runs when it's needed (so certainly after the app is loaded), or can be moved to `Meteor.startup` without a problem. Why do you need the `collectionVariable` in the file body? You're probably trying to achieve something that's not in the "Meteor way".

Comment: I have some dynamic infoboxes that will be displayed in google map based on database details . I am trying to give some jquery effect to the infoboxes custom divs when the data changes. The issue is that the jquery code is not working, as it seems the div elements creation is not fully complete for it to work.