# How do you fix file load order problems using Meteor.startup?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

Many resources on the internet (including here) suggest using [`Meteor.startup`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_startup) to fix dependency issues caused by the order in which JS files load. However, nobody spells out exactly how this is accomplished.

Specifically, it seems like file order dependency is the reason I can't get my posts.coffee collection to recognize permissions defined in my permissions.coffee. I think this is happening because posts.coffee is in /lib/collections, whereas permissions.coffee is in /lib, and files in subdirectories get loaded first. (Incidentally, I would prefer /collections to be in the root directory, but I had to move it into /lib previously to solve a similar problem.)

Here is my posts.coffee:

```
@Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts')

Posts.allow(
  update: ownsDocument
  remove: ownsDocument
)

Meteor.methods(
  ...
```

And here is my permissions.coffee:

```
@ownsDocument = (userId, doc)->
  doc && doc.userId == userId
```

(This is all from the "Discover Meteor" book tutorial, by the way, around [these commits](https://github.com/SachaG/Microscope/commits/chapter8-2), except in CoffeeScript.)

My question: Assuming my analysis of the problem is correct, how would you solve it using `Meteor.startup`? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956578/uncaught-referenceerror-collection-is-not-defined) is hard for me to interpret; one interpretation is that I should wrap `Posts.allow(...)` in `Meteor.startup` somehow, but that seems really clumsy. Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems like there should be one general/config file with all the necessary startup code, and specific controllers should remain ignorant of it.

BTW, I realize I could hack a solution by taking advantage of Meteor's default file load ordering rules (e.g. /lib first; subdirectories first; main.* last; alphabetically), but that's a really inelegant solution to what should be a simple problem. I don't want to have to append "a" in front of a filename or create spurious directories just to get it load before another file.

One last note: I'm using CoffeeScript, and I wonder if the way CS handles global scope has something to do with it. (E.g., instead of defining my `Posts` collection as a JS variable without the `var` keyword, in CS I have to define is as `@Posts`, which I believe makes it a property of the window.)

Comment: Are you putting all permissions for all collections in one file? It might be easier and more organized to put your allow/deny rules in the same files as your Collection definitions. Besides, it's generally bad practice to clobber the global namespace with functions specific to a certain implementation detail like your `@ownsDocument` function. But it really sounds like the problem is your intended directory structure. Do parts of your app other than collections need access to `permissions.coffee`? If it is a library of code to be used by collections, put it in `lib/collections/lib/`

Comment: Another solution may be to abstract your collection code into a Meteorite package (just put it in `packages/`, don't publish it to Atmosphere). This gives you full control over the directory structure and file load order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do just that:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  Posts.allow(
    ...
  )
```

Basically, any piece of code that uses a variable defined in another file should be preceded by `Meteor.startup ->`, unless you are sure that the loading order is correct (the variable is in lib, for example).

Yes, the loading order is poorly chosen.

Comment: Thanks! 

Just out of curiosity, what do you think of the smart packages approach matb33 mentioned below?

Comment: I think that one of Meteor strengths is in the ease of development: when you need to move things or make a new file, you just add the file and continue to work without having to think about file list, class declarations and so on. Moving the app code you work on to a smart package defies this benefit, as now you need to manage the file list yourself. That being said, smart packages are great for what they're intended - small, reusable pieces of code that probably doesn't change much. I've got lots of them for such purposes - just don't use them for the regular app code.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you consider working entirely out of smart packages. That's how Meteor itself is largely written.

I go into more detail here: http://www.matb33.me/2013/09/05/meteor-project-structure.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I will seriously consider it for a future project, but it doesn't actually address my question about Meteor.startup : )